# Mongo is returning convert from BSON to EOO error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm receiving this error: (node:5955) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): MongoError: can't convert from BSON type EOO to Date

I have the following mongoose model:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('atendimento', {
    id: String,
    id_atendimento: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    id_cliente: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    id_user: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    user_nome: String,
    cliente_nome: String,
    id_atendente: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    atendente_nome: String,
    atendente_imagem: String,
    setor: Number,
    descricao: String,
    status: String,
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    inicio: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    fim: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    update: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

My query is this one:

```
const testeAtM = atendimentos.aggregate([
            { "$group" : {_id:"$id_atendente", totaltest:{$sum:1}}},
            { '$group' : {
                '_id': {
                    'month': { '$month': '$date' }
                },
                    'sum' : { '$sum': 1}
                } },
            { '$group' : {
                '_id': null,
                    'resptest': { '$push': '$$ROOT'}
                }},
        ]).exec();
```

What I want to do is:

Check the number of ocurrences of id_atendente per month, maybe there is something wrong with the query itself.

Expected JSON is something like this:

```
 {
            "_id": 1,
            "totaltest": 36
            "month": 5
        },
 {
            "_id": 1,
            "totaltest": 108
            "month": 6
        },

 {
            "_id": 2,
            "totaltest": 76
            "month": 6
        },
 {
            "_id": 2,
            "totaltest": 206
            "month": 8
        },

 {
            "_id": 1,
            "totaltest": 90
            "month": 7
        },
```

Hoping to get some help! Thanks in advance.

I'm using mongoDB 3.2 by the way.

Comment: What count is  `totalTest` ?

Comment: totalTest is what I want to use to see how many times id_atendente repeats. I've got this working but it's for checking how many occurences of the same id_atendente exists.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have time to answer better yesterday. Like, my intention with totalTest is count how many occurrences an id has in a month. Like, on month 5 id 1 had 36 occurrences.

Comment: No issues. Try to group both on id and month.

Comment: So I'm supposed to put this `{_id:"$id_atendente", totaltest:{$sum:1}` inside a query like this one:    `{ '$group' : {
                     '_id': {
                         'month': { '$month': '$date' },
                        {_id:"$id_atendente", totaltest:{$sum:1}
                     },
                     'sum' : { '$sum': 1}
                 } },
             { '$group' : {
                     '_id': null,
                     'resptest': { '$push': '$$ROOT'}
                 }},
         ]).exec();` ?

Comment: No. Just try `{ '$group' : { '_id': {'id_atendente':"$id_atendente", 'month': { '$month': '$date' }}, 'sum' : { '$sum': 1} } }`

Comment: Okay, I tried it using mongo shell and it seems to be working, now I need to use $push and $$ROOT to put it into an array, I tried doing the same way that I did before using _id: null and declaring a variable like this `test: {'$push': '$$ROOT}` and it didn't work

Comment: That looks correct. What is not working ?

Comment: Manage to fix it, I forgot to pass it to the front end. You can add an answer to my question so I'll accept it since you helped me a lot, thank you!